# Azure long-term daily backup

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, backup, database-backups, azure-backup-vault

I use long-term backups in azure.
Now backups created every week and I want create backup every day but I don't see this option.

[Here it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-long-term-retention) is only about the possibility of weekly, monthly and annual backups

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full backups scheduled that occur every day is not possible with long-term backups and Azure SQL Database automatic backups. You already have daily differential backups and TLog backups every 5-10 minutes with [automatic SQL Database backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automated-backups).